# Why is "echo $SHELL" always returning /bin/tcsh

Tags: bash, shell, tcsh

I have the following simple shell script:

[test.sh]

```
#! /bin/bash
echo $SHELL
```

**Why am I am always getting a console output of `/bin/tsch` in all the following scenarios?**

1) In the terminal, run the following:

```
% ./test.sh
```

2) In the terminal, run the following:

```
% bash
$ ./test.sh
```

3) In the terminal, run the following:

```
% bash ./test.sh
```

As you can probably tell from the `%` cursor, the terminal starts with tcsh by default. I am confused by why `#! /bin/bash` in the script and `bash` in the command line are not affecting the value of `$SHELL`.

Comment: ... Because it's the user's *login* shell...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Bash Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Variables) in the manual:

> SHELL
>
> > The full pathname to the shell is kept in this environment variable. **If it is not set when the shell starts**, Bash assigns to it the full pathname of the current user’s login shell.

My emphasis.

If you want the path to the current bash executable, use `$BASH`. See the above link to the docs.

Comment: See also `bash -c 'set | grep ^BASH'`